# Javascript splitting string by given array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have given string `"asdlfjsahdkljahskl"` and have given array `[1,2,3,1,7,2,1,2]`.My final output should be `a`, `sd`, `lfj`, `s`, `ahdklja`, `hs`, `kl`.

I know how to split the string but I don't know how to compare the string and cut according to given array

HTML Code

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
var width = [1,4,2,6,1,1,10,1];

function myFunction() {
    var str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var res = str.split("");

    for(var j=0; j.length;j++){
        document.write(width[j]);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
 }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `j.length` does not make any sense since it is a number.

Comment: you can keep the loop. You will need array for result and local variable keeping rest of the string after sub

Comment: Your expected output is probably wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could slice the string with a stored value and a new length.

```js
var string = "asdlfjsahdkljahskl",
    array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2],
    p = 0,
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        return string.slice(p, p += a);
    });

console.log(result);
```

The same with a `for` loop

```js
var string = "asdlfjsahdkljahskl",
    array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2],
    p = 0,
    i = 0,
    result = []


for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result.push(string.slice(p, p + array[i]));
    p += array[i];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: how would this be possible without .map

Comment: @danny you can use any iterator, honestly (assuming you use them properly) - my answer uses `.forEach()` if you are interested in that one

Comment: I am beginner, so I am looking very simple logic not using for each or .map. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string="asdlfjsahdkljahsxkl",
    array=[1,2,3,1,7,2,1,2];
function myFunction() {
array.forEach(function(index){
  var yourvalue=string.slice(0,index);
  console.log(yourvalue);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += yourvalue+'\n';
  string=string.slice(index,string.length);
});
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Nina's answer is to convert your string to an array, like you have done, and use the `.splice()` function like so:

```js
var str = "asdlfjsahdkljahskl",
  arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2];

function extractValues (str, strLens) {
  str = str.split("");
  strLens.forEach(function (strLen) {
    console.log(str.splice(0, strLen).join(""));
  });
}
extractValues(str, arr);
```

Comment: what does .foreach do ? does it compare every array element. I am running on my local editor is giving me error

Comment: @danny https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods